# Communication between C# and Java :Process

Tags: c#, java, process, compilation, native

I search to make a binding beteewn a Java Process and a C# Process.
My last idea is : compile a java process into a .exe, in order to directly launch it from the c# process without pass by java.exe

Is it possible? if yes, could you help me a little please?

Have a good day

edit : this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94882/what-is-the-best-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-java-and-net-3-5) is not an answer to my question, because if i wanted use process, it's because i want that c# process run java process

Comment: You cannot compile a Java source file into an `exe`; what you can do is programatically invoke a JVM via a C/C++ API; maybe a wrapper exists in C#?

Comment: If they "only" have to communicate, you can use the local network stack (sockets). Or start the process and use std.in/out streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Process` framework to start your Java program (compiled as a runnable JAR) and pass in command-line parameters which allows the Java program to "know" how to behave, assuming the communication isn't incredibly complex between the two programs.

```
Process javaProcess = new Process();
javaProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Path\\To\\yourJavaProgram.jar";
javaProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "EXECUTE_FROM_C_SHARP"; //or whatever
javaProcess.Start();

//Wait for the Java program to finish doing its thing before resuming
javaProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: we can do that? i always see that we must pass by java.exe ! So really thank you, i'll try it soon

Comment: Are you sur that it works? because i have an error when i try it (but i can read before it disappear). Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the stdin and stout streams.  Start a new process in C# calling the java program.  The process's stdin will route to the stdin of the java process (System.in by default).  Same for stdout.